# imagesrcset HTML Validation Shows Expected single descriptor but found extraneous descriptor

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

I am preloading responsive images and it seems to work just fine, validating the correct image is loaded at different widths in Chrome-Dev-Network.  Yet when running HTML validation from https://validator.w3.org/, I get

> Error: Bad value for attribute imagesrcset on element link: Expected
> single descriptor but found extraneous descriptor
> /sites/default/files/resp_img/ayahuasca-painting-wide.webp at
> …ting-wide.webp

The code in my page header is

```
  <link rel="preload" as="image" fetchpriority="high"
     imagesrcset= "/sites/default/files/resp_img/ayahuasca-painting-mobile.webp 500w,
                    /sites/default/files/resp_img/ayahuasca-painting-mobile-landscape.webp 770w,
                    /sites/default/files/resp_img/ayahuasca-painting-tablet.webp 995w,
                    /sites/default/files/resp_img/ayahuasca-painting-desktop.webp 1194w
                    /sites/default/files/resp_img/ayahuasca-painting-wide.webp 1389w"
                    imagesizes="100vw" >
```

The images are used as background image with css based on break points.

```
@media screen and  (min-width: 576px) {
.splash{
  background-image: url("/sites/default/files/resp_img/ayahuasca-painting-mobile-landscape.webp");
}
}
```

I have spent a fair amount of time looking for a way to remove this validation error.  What do I need to change to resolve the validation error and still have it load the correct image based on screen width?